# Where should a cron job record its periodic actions log

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, logging, cron

Consider a python script which is run on a cron job. This particular script backups up servers, but this question is not specific to that functionality.

Below is a list of servers to back up, based on period:

```
servers = {}
servers['hourly'] = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
servers['daily'] = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma']
servers['weekly'] = ['mercury', 'venus', 'earth', 'mars']
```

The cron job run hourly:

```
$ crontab -l
0 * * * * /path/to/backup.py
```

**How should the script check if it should run the hourly, daily, or weekly cron job?** In a perfect world I would run the hourly job each time, run the daily job if `datetime.now().hour == 0` and run the weekly job if `datetime.now().hour == 0 and datetime.now().isoweekday() == 0`. However the world is not perfect and the cron job may fail to run, or the computer may be shut off for a period of time, so I need to record a log and check it to see if the jobs need to be run.

What is the best / recommended / standard / Pythonic way to do this? Should I use an .sqlite database? A plain text file? **Where should I store it?**

My intuitive inclination is a plain text file in `/var/log/backup.log`. However this script is currently running as an unprivileged user and I'd like to keep it that way. Also, I believe that the log will get large quickly, so perhaps sqlite is better as I will be querying it each run.

Currently the script runs on an Ubuntu desktop, but we would like to keep the option of running it on a Windows desktop open as well.

Comment: Why not just pass a string argument to the script and check sys.argv[1]? Cron will handle the scheduling itself and the job will "know" which mode it's running under.

Comment: @MarkR.: What string argument do you suggest? How will the script "know" which mode it is running under? How will the script know if the computer was turned off at midnight and it needs to run the daily jobs even though it is 9:00 AM?